# WKWebView - Get query parameters of html form

Tags: objective-c, webview, webkit, wkwebview

I've just made the switch from UIWebView to WKWebView.
I have an HTML file (loaded as string) which includes an HTML form with one input with type text, and a submit button.

Using UIWebView, the URL included the value of the input on the URL as a query parameter. (some-url.index?key=value)

When switched to WKWebView, the URL does not include the parameters as part of the URL.

In UIWebView I was getting the URL like so:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"Loading URL :%@",request.URL.absoluteString);
}
```

In WKWebView I'm getting the URL like so:

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(nonnull WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);

    NSLog(@"Loading URL :%@", navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString);
}
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other users that encounter this issue in the future:

After digging a bit, it seems that in WKWebView in order to have query parameters passed in the url, the url must have a valid scheme (http://, https://, etc..)

All other ways failed for me.